# How is a custom derived query POST added to spring data REST?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring data REST project I am using to learn.

Right now I want to set up a query in this repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>
```

namely, this guy:

```
    @RestResource(path = "login", rel = "login")
    User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
```

A basic repository is easy to set up. So are custom GET requests like:

```
List<Item> findByType(@Param("type") String type);
```

or

```
@RestResource(path = "byMaxPrice")
@Query("SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE i.price <= :maxPrice")
List<Item> findItemsLessThan(@Param("maxPrice") double maxPrice);
```

But these are still GET requests. I would like to use a POST request. The `method = RequestMapping.POST` markup isn't accepted by `@RestResource` .. and I dont see any mention of different request types in the documentation. how do I do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to use POST instead of GET for fetching the data?

Comment: I dont want my response here to derail my question, there are obviously some reasons to always prefer POST (maybe you dont like url skimming routers or something).. but I'm glad to answer. It is simply natural to pass an object directly with angular to the spring back end. I could interrogate the data I get from ng-model and build a response, or I could simply open a post and pass it a single object. Its _more natural_

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom `Controller` to handle POST requests. If you just want to do POST for the default Repository methods, unfortunately, you still have to make a pass through `Controller`

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class MyController implements Serializable {

...
@RequestMapping(value = "/myConstroller/myPostMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST
     , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody List<MyObjects>  updateMyObjectList(
    @RequestBody List<MyObjects> objects) { 
    // Call your repository method here, or a custom service, or whatever
}
```

See [Spring MVC docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for further information, specifically section [5.2.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_http_methods), which describes the default HTTP Method support for Repositories, and [16.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers), which gives a custom Controller example.

From 5.2.1:

> POST
>
> Creates a new entity from the given request body.

Thus, POST is supported, but not to do what you are trying to do. If you want to "hide" URL parameters by using POST instead of GET, you need a custom Controller.

Comment: "You need to define a custom Controller to handle POST requests" can you give me a specific reference, rather than just indicating a book I should read? I want to mark this as the answer, but you don't properly source your claim.. and for all I know, it is not actually correct.

Comment: I appreciate it but section 5.2.1 talks about that Controllers _do_ provide POST, but not that data REST Repositories _do not_ provide POST.

Comment: @robertotomás I edited my answer, but if you read the doc, you'd see it doesn't support POST to do what you're trying to do. There is no configuration I know of to make the default Controller SDR provides for you support POST for find* requests.